# Extjs 4.1 - How to loadData from a Store to another Store

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a `store1` with `autoLoad:true`

```
           store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'example.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'results'    // see json output                         
            }
        }
    });
```

and i have a grid has store2 with `autoload:false`

```
           store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'example.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'results'    // see json output                         
            }
        }
    });
```

I don't want load store2 again. I want get from store1 like

```
grid.store2.loadData(store1.data) // fail
```

But how to do that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can benefit from store's `load` event, try something like this:

```
store1.addListener('load', function(records, operation, success) {
   if(success) {
      var obj = new Object();
      obj.success = true;
      obj.results = records;
      grid.store2.loadData(obj);
   }
});
```

Comment: but how to get records without function(records, operation, success) { b/c my grid will init later :(

Comment: yeah i just get it by using getRange() and everything working thank :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add before your code. sortOnLoad=false;

```
grid.store2.sortOnLoad=false
grid.store2.loadData(store1.data) // fail
```